# What does "object expression" mean in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

The term "object expression" first appears in the C++11 draft standard in:

> **3.4.5 Class member access** [basic.lookup.classref]
>
> 1. In a class member access expression (5.2.5), if the . or -> token is immediately followed by an identifier followed by a <, the identifier must be looked up to determine whether the < is the beginning of a template argument list (14.2) or a less-than operator. The identifier is first looked up in the class of the object expression. If the identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression and shall name a class template.

I could find the definition of "Object Expression" on the web for [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233237.aspx) but not for C++.

Is this a commonly understood term? What does it mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you follow to 5.2.5 [expr.ref], you'll read in paragraph 3:

> 3 Abbreviating *postfix-expression*.*id-expression* as `E1.E2`, `E1` is called the *object expression.* ...

Previously, paragraph 2 of that section defines `E1 -> E2` in terms of `(*(E1)).E2`, so this quote from paragraph 3 actually covers both `.` and `->` operators.

Comment: Does that mean a `struct` is also an object expression, or is a "structure expression" a separate syntactic component?

Comment: @JefferyThomas I don't follow. Can you clarify what you mean? What is a "structure expression?"

Comment: @Angew sorry "structure expression" was just something I made up. I wondered if object expression covered the left-hand side selecting a field in a structure. According to haccks it does.

Comment: @JefferyThomas; Yes. `struct` as well as `union` are also an object expression because ultimately they are [class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23933679/2455888).

Comment: @JefferyThomas - it isn't _class-expression_ so your derived _structure-expression_ does not follow the pattern. The object here is simply the instance of a class/struct/union type.

Comment: @Angew, thanks for the answer. I wonder how many such terms are used in the standard before they are defined.

Comment: @RSahu Many. C++ is so complex that many parts interact with each other. I believe a linear ordering with no used-before-defined terms exists, but it would be jumping all over the place topically.